# Bison and C++ with nested namespaces wont compile for me

Tags: c++, c++11, bison, flex-lexer

I've been banging my head all day trying to fix this. I have a `bison/flex/c++` [project](https://github.com/Naddiseo/NDE/tree/rework/script) I'm working on, ignoring the fact that the semantic actions are incomplete and will cause compile errors when it gets there, I can't get the generated parser to compile. I get the following:

```
g++ -I. -g3 -std=c++0x -DYYDEBUG=1 -Werror -Wfatal-errors -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-all -o ndes.bin Parser.cpp Scanner.cpp Driver.cpp
Parser.cpp:174:3: error: prototype for ‘nde::script::Parser::Parser(nde::script::Driver&)’ does not match any in class ‘nde::script::Parser’
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Now, judging from the error, I thought it would be straight forward to fix: the header file doesn't match the source file. So, I open them up, and I can't find a difference between them.

The full source to my project is in the github link above, using the "rework" branch under the "script" folder. I'm using `g++ 4.6.1`, `flex 2.5.35`, and `bison 2.4.1`. The files in question are `Parser.[ch]pp` which are generated by bison.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to see the generated code. Can you add it to your repository or otherwise make it available somewhere?

Comment: Done. Generated files added to git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 namespace Foo {
     class Bar;
     void x (class Bar); // refers to class Foo::Bar
     void y (class Baz); // refers to class ::Baz
 }
```

Forward-declare `class Driver` in the namespace.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was stuck on this a whole day.